# Cloud Foundry CLI version 6.11.2 or later is required for the IBM Containers plug-in. Upgrade your Cloud Foundry CLI installation to continue

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

```
cf -v
cf version 6.13.0-e68ce0f-2015-10-15T22:53:58+00:00

Plugin IBM-Containers v0.8.723 successfully installed.

cf ic login

Expect: login successfully
Actual: Cloud Foundry CLI version 6.11.2 or later is required for the IBM Containers plug-in. Upgrade your Cloud Foundry CLI installation to continue.
```

How could this happened? I have installed the latest cf...

Comment: This does look like a bug. Could you raise a ticket and someone will look into this?

Comment: The `ice` tooling can be used instead of the `cf ic` plugin if this is a bug

Comment: @James Thomas Thanks for ur comment, I have opened an issue in github.

Comment: @jimmc Thanks for ur suggestion, I have installed the `ice` and it works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATED 26 October 2015** the latest version (0.8.763 or later) of the `cf ic` plugin supports the 6.13 version of `cf`.

Run `cf ic update` and you should see the commands you need to run to upgrade the plugin (varies by operating system). Or [check the documentation](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_cli_cfic.html#container_cli_cfic_upgrade).

---

**Previous answer follows:**

Currently (19 October 2015) the IBM-Containers plugin (version 0.8.723 or earlier) is not compatible with the 6.13.x version of `cf`. We're working on patching our plugin. Sorry about that.

In the meantime, you can install [CF 6.12.4](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/releases/tag/v6.12.4) and then [install the IBM Containers plugin](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_cli_cfic.html#container_cli_cfic_install). Or use the [`ice` tools](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_cli_ice_ov.html)